# How to change matplotlib line color in scipy.spatial.delaunay_plot_2d

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the delaunay_plot_2d function in scipy.spatial; sparse documentation here:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.delaunay_plot_2d.html#scipy.spatial.delaunay_plot_2d

Does anyone know how to change the line color? The default is red. The delaunay_plot_2d function does not accept keywords. I suspect this is a general matplotlib question (e.g., how to get to line color from a Figure), but I can't find the answer anywhere. Thanks!

Here's a code snippet inspired by @ofri-raviv (though this one makes the lines green):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay, delaunay_plot_2d

x = np.random.normal(size=(10,2))
d = Delaunay(x)
h = delaunay_plot_2d(d)
```

Again, modifying @ofri-raviv 's code below, this seems to work.

```
for l in h.axes[0].get_children():
    if type(l) is Line2D:
        l.set_color('0.75')
```

That changes **every** line to have color '0.75'. But that's good enough.

Comment: Give a minimum working example for us to play around with and i'm sure someone will be able to come up with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay, delaunay_plot_2d
x = randn(100,2)
d = Delaunay(x)
a = delaunay_plot_2d(d)
patch = [l for l in a.axes[0].get_children() if type(l) is matplotlib.patches.PathPatch][0]
```

Then you can set the color of the patch object:

```
patch.set_color('black')
```

You may need to use [draw](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.draw) to make your update visible.

Comment: There is no PathPatch that 'patch' list.